# Outlook 2010 still automatically downloading pictures even though its turned off

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

One of my users at work has received an email with what looks like a webbug image in; however the URL is a UNC network path "\\af12.mail.ru\cgi-bin\" and Outlook pops up a "Connecting to: \\af12.mail.ru\cgi-bin\" message as it tries to connect, so I checked the automatic download settings and made sure they were set to not allow automatic download:

[image: all Permit options turned off]

After restarting Outlook and opening the email the connecting message came up again, I've checked the settings and they are still as I've set them.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a Registry Key to block this:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common

Dword: BlockHTTPImages

Value: 1

If issue continues, we can run outlook in safe mode as suggested in [this TechNet thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/2119fe11-e9f6-47de-a957-3ce67a32779d/outlook-2013-contact-the-server-for-information?forum=outlook) to see the result.

To do this, please exit Outlook. Press Win +R to open Run. Type outlook /safe and then click Enter.